# How to handle error programmatically which can be occurred of exceeding the free Firebase database limitation

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using free Firebase database in my app. As it has a few limitation in concurrent connections and database size, when it exceed the limitation what kind of error will occur to user and how to handle it and is there any kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main question should be, what happens when we reach the limit of `concurrent connections`? Meaning the `maximum number of writes per seconds`.

If you have a very popular app, you most likely already reached that limit, and at that moment, the Firebase database will start to queue up the number of writes that cannot be written on the disk straight away. With other words, Firebase biulds a `buffer of pendings write operations`. If the write volum goes down, it will start caching up with the buffer.

The answer to your question, is **no**, there is no way to programmatically catch an exception, when Firebase Realtime database reaches the limit. This is happening because at that moment, there is no exception that is thrown. There is also no method that has as a return value, the maximum number of connections.

But, there is although a workaroung in which you can attach a `CompletionListener` on the node that you are interested. If you'll see that the time between when you start the write operation and the time when it completes `goes up`, it means that you're buffered (queued). This is how you can know when the 100 simultaneous connection is reached.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Answer (score 0):

If you've received an email alert or notification in the Firebase console that you've exceeded your Realtime Database usage limits, you can address it based on the usage limit you've exceeded. To see your Realtime Database usage, go to the Realtime Database usage section of the Firebase console.

**If you're over your download limit**, you can upgrade your Firebase plan or wait until your download limit resets at the start of your next billing cycle. To decrease your downloads, try the following steps:

- Add queries to limit the data that your listen operations return.
- Check for unindexed queries.
- Use listeners that only download updates to data — for example, on()
  instead of once().
- Use security rules to block unauthorized downloads.

**If you're over your storage limit**, upgrade your plan to avoid service disruptions. To reduce the amount of data in your database, try the following steps:

Run periodic cleanup jobs.
Reduce any duplicate data in your database.
Note that it may take some time to see any data deletions reflected in your storage allotment.

**If you're over your simultaneous database connections limit**, upgrade your plan to avoid any service disruptions. To manage simultaneous connections to your database, try connecting via users via the REST API if they don't require a realtime connection.